# Sitecore publish not working after renaming item

Tags: sitecore, publish

I'm having a weird that's happening only on live and UAT environment. Locally and on QA works as expected.

The issue is:

1. I add a new item version
2. I rename the item
3. Publish

Expected behaviour: url to be updated; 
What happens: url is not updated.

As a workaround, I rename the item, publish it, then add a new version.

Sitecore version: 8.2 rev 180406

Comment: Is the item in the final workflow step?

Comment: No matter what workflow step is, it happens the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've open a ticket on Sitecore Support Portal, they provided a fix and I deployed it. After several testing scenarios the issue no longer reproduce.

Comment: Can you please share the fix ?

Answer (score 0):

Long shot, but has this instance been upgraded from a previous version? This was a known issue with v8.2 through Update 4. Check the version of Sitecore.Kernel.dll in that environment (as this was the file that got patched when issuing a support request).